# Open Ubuntu DIrectory In WIndows?

Tags: 12.04, boot, command-line, login

My Ubuntu has a problem with /etc/rc.local , because of it , my Ubuntu won't boot to desktop . So I want to remove some entries in rc.local on Windows , how can I do it ? Thanks .
(I think I can't open a terminal in login screen.)

(sorry bad English)

Answer (score 0):

if your Ubuntu Filesystem is EXT4 (or 2 or 3) you can mount it in Windows 
via EXTFS from Paragon Software (Freeware). Just google for it....

best regards,
Tobi

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to access the drive from Windows to repair this, so long as you can get Ubuntu's login screen up.

From the Ubuntu login screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to bring up a TTY terminal. Log in using your regular username and password, and then use a command line editor (`vim`, `nano`, etc... - so the command would be `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`) to make the changes you need. Once you're done, you can reboot the computer using `sudo reboot`, and hopefully you should be able to log in as usual afterwards.

To get back to the GUI without rebooting, you can instead press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to the main session (a reboot is probably the better option here, just mentioning how to get back to the regular session for completeness' sake - useful if you want to use the TTY terminals and get back to normal without shutting down).